# Swift: Dynamic App Icon Not Displaying Correctly

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm new to Swift, and I'm trying to let the user change the app icon dinamically.

The problem is that when I change the icon theoretically the icon gets changed (since I see the model popping up), but the actual icon image is not displayed and I get the icon to be the "undefined" app icon.

All the images are `1024 × 1024` and added to the `Assets`

This is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation


class IconViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentIconName: String? = UIApplication.shared.alternateIconName
    
    func changeIcon(to icon: AppIcon) {
        UIApplication.shared.setAlternateIconName(icon.iconName) { error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error changing app icon: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                } else {
                    print("App icon changed successfully to!", icon.iconName)
                    self.currentIconName = icon.iconName
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AppIcon: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let iconName: String?
    let displayName: String
    let image: Image
}

let appIcons = [
    AppIcon(iconName: nil, displayName: "Default", image: Image("icon")),
    AppIcon(iconName: "BlackBlue", displayName: "Blue & Black", image: Image("blueblack")),
    AppIcon(iconName: "Dune", displayName: "Dune", image: Image("dune")),
    AppIcon(iconName: "Elegant", displayName: "Classy", image: Image("elegant")),
    AppIcon(iconName: "Minimal", displayName: "Minimal", image: Image("minimal"))
]

struct IconSelectionView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: IconViewModel
    var icons: [AppIcon]
    let columns: [GridItem] = Array(repeating: .init(.flexible()), count: 3) // Set the number of columns you want
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(icons) { icon in
                    Button(action: {
                        viewModel.changeIcon(to: icon)
                    }) {
                        VStack {
                            icon.image
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .frame(width: 60, height: 60) // Set the size as needed
                                .overlay(
                                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
                                        .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: viewModel.currentIconName == icon.iconName ? 3 : 0)
                                )
                            
                            Text(icon.displayName)
                                .font(.caption)
                                .foregroundColor(.primary)
                        }
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.secondary.opacity(0.1))
                        .cornerRadius(12)
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

[image: info.plist]

Video:

[video: current app icon switching problem](https://imgur.com/a/6oURc2w)

Comment: Hi Edoardo! I answered your question. Are you italian? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you did not added those assets as **iOS app icons**. The way I add new icons to an iOS app is the following:

**1.** Add the assets to the **assets catalog**. Maybe create a folder called **AppIcons** for the sake of order:

[image: Add App Icons]

**2.** Then add your new icon dragging it in the 1024x1024 box like you normally would with a modern project.

**3.** Go to settings and search for *icon* and add all of the alternate app icon names to the **Alternate App Icons Sets**

[image: Alternate App Icons Sets]

[image: Add Alternate Icon names]

**4.** In your code then you can as you are already doing:

```
UIApplication.shared.setAlternateIconName(icon) {error in
    if error != nil {
        print("Failed to request icon \(icon)")
        return
    }
    print("Icon changed to \(icon)")
}
```

Let me know if this solved your problem!